# ag-grid angular - refresh group row on selection change

Tags: angular, angular7, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I've combed the docs and API references, but I'm not seeing a way to trigger a refresh to a group row when a selection changes has been made to it's children.

Working ag-grid in angular 7, I'm using a custom renderer for the group inner and would like to be able to change the styling of the group based on the selection being made. I would prefer to not rerender the grid, but only refresh the group row if possible.

Aside from storing the selection in a store, is there any way to trigger such a refresh on a group row?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for doing this

```
onCellChanged() {

  Data = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
```

make key-value pair by passing some sort of id

After using this

```
    this.gridApi.forEachNode(function(rowNode) {}
```

compare id in both and

Pass this into  ag-grid function
in which you are setting your grid data